# Garage door trolley no longer attached

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener, garage-door

The trolley on our garage door is no longer attached to the garage door opener track (with the operator) and the arm is hanging loose. I wasn't there when the trolley fell off the track, but was told that the trolley was disconnected from the operator and fell off when the garage door was lifted up.

1. From my research this doesn't seem to be a common issue. What could
   cause this? I don't see any obvious damage to the trolley, but can
   post additional pictures if need be.
2. Does this mean the trolley needs to be replaced?
3. How can I reattach the trolley? I don't see an easy
   way to slip it over the track, so it seems like the only options are
   taking the trolley apart and putting it back together once it's back
   in place or taking the track down and then slipping the trolley
   over.

--- Edit(s) ---
Current state of the door
[image: Garage door down]

Picture of the trolley
[image]

Comment: A few pictures would help us see what you see.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Jack! I just added an image of the arm and the trolley. If there is anything specific that could be helpful let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by calling our neighbor, who realized that the trolley was too loose and the left lip was a bit curved. We flattened the lip (with a hammer) and then squeezed it along the other axis (v-shaped cut) using a vice. We then slipped the trolley back on and it worked without any issues.

**Note:** When squeezing the trolley to get a tighter v-shape, the metal is rather springy. You need to tighten the vice quite a bit to get it to deform the right amount.